# Rule of three for inner class, outer class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have class that is defined like

*A.h*

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <vector>

class A
{
    int n;
    std::vector<A::B> elements;
    public:
        A();
        A(int);
        class B
        {
            int m;
            A* a;
            public:
                B();
                B(int);
                B(int, A*);
        };

};

#endif
```

*A.cpp*

```
#include "A.h"

A::A()
 : n(0)
{

}

A::A(int x)
 : n(x), elements(std::vector<A::B>(n))
{
    for (int j = 0; j < this->n; j++)
    {
        B newElement(j, this);
        this->elements[j] = newElement;
    }
}

A::B::B()
 : m(0), a(0)
{

}

A::B::B(int j)
 : m(j), a(0)
{

}

A::B::B(int j, A* aPtr)
 : m(j), a(aPtr)
{

}
```

How should I define copy constructors, overloaded assignment operators, and destructors such that I avoid infinite recursion on deletion, and that I avoid, if possible, having to use `new`? `A::B` needs pointer to `A` to define operators that programmer may decide to add. Also, programmer may decide to write class C that extends A and `C::D` that extends `A::B`

Comment: Save yourself some hassles and don't use nested classes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I suppose The Professor wouldn't be pleased.

Comment: In that case, the OP should ask the Professor, not StackOverflow. :-)

Comment: This is very unclear. You don't have any user-defined destructors, so why do you want to define any of the other operations? Which invariants are non-trivial here?

Comment: "programmer may decide to write class C that extends A and C::D that extends A::B"  - not with this design they can't

Comment: Well, it's possible to have class C extending class A here. But `C::D` will not be able to extend `A::B`, for the obvious reasons.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have to use nested classes here, as I am trying to implement the integer group and integer ring mathematical structures, and wish to use actual + and * on their elements, which the structures have. (Group is equipped with * and ring is group under addition)

Comment: @Kerrek, I am trying to add destructors, so as to adhere to the rule of three.

Comment: @MikeWarren: You got everything the wrong way round. The Ro3 says that *if* you have a destructor, then you also need the other special members. It does *niot* say that you need to have a destructor.

Comment: But I need copy constructors, and need to know how to properly implement all this

Comment: OK, you may need copy and move operations for `A`, that's true, but probably no destructor, since your invariants don't contain resources -- the invariant is only that elements of the vector point to the current instance. The Ro3 isn't absolute; it says that you *may* need all three if you have any one of the special members -- but it's mandatory only when the reason that you have special members is that you're managing resources.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm not in C++11.

Comment: I'm not sure there's an airtight design for `B`: you clearly need to be able to copy and assign it (given that the vector needs to reallocate), but at the same time you don't want to overwrite `B` elements with values that contain the wrong `A` pointer.  This will require cooperation from `A`, i.e. access to the vector should be kept private, and elements should be checked at that point.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is there a way that it can happen, given the parameters I laid down in the comments?

Comment: No there isn't. You cannot avoid the basic, fundamental fact that the vector will contain `A::B` objects. You can create a subclass of `A::B` as much as you wanted, but no suclass of `A` can change what the vector contains, and no subclass of `B` can avoid being sliced away when it's shoved into the vector. C++ does not work this way.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I define copy constructors, overloaded assignment operators, and destructors such that I avoid infinite recursion on deletion, and that I avoid, if possible, having to use new

Ownership of `A::elements` is determined by your declaration. `~A` is going to destroy any `B`'s in the owned elements member. This means that `A::B::a` likely has to be treated as an unowned pointer and not deleted when `~B` is run. If, under some circumstances, `A::B::a` is owned by an instance of `B`, then `B` likely needs to add a member to track this ownership and free a only under these circumstances. Alternatively `A::B::a` could be declared as `std::shared_ptr<A>` (or similar). However, remember that `std::shared_ptr` can still potentially leak if ownership is circular.

This ambiguity and complexity would be avoided if it's possible to determine 'what owns what' and come up with a relationship that is less opaque than 'everything owns everything else'.

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to implement `IntegerGroup`, `IntegerRing`, which are C++ implementations of the integer group and integer ring structures in mathematics.

Comment: Also, what if only the pointer was copied, and no `new` was used?

Comment: That suggests an informal weak relationship, which is a common, if unsafe, C++ pattern.