# Pointers to member functions of another object

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

My situation is thus:
I have two classes: A,B. A contains`std::vector<B>`, and B requires function pointer from A to initialize its own operations.

(I am trying to implement the integer group and integer ring mathematical structures in c++)

What is the safest way to accomplish this? (I learned that giving B a pointer to A causes unexpected behaviour in A. I tried it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500860/rule-of-three-for-inner-class-outer-class). )

Now that I am at my computer, I shall post my codebase (I made B member class to A, so as to minimize the sections I have to type up):

*A.h*

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <vector>

class A
{
    public:
        A(int);
        static int defaultMultiply(int, int);
        int multiply(int, int);
        class B
        {
            public: 
                typedef int(*defaultMultiplication)(int, int);
                typedef int(A::*multiplication)(int, int);
                B();
                B(int, int, multiplication);
                B operator*(const B&);

            protected:
                int m, parentGroupSize;
                multiplication mult;
                defaultMultiplication defMult;

        };
    private: 
        int n; 
        std::vector<A::B> elements;

};

#endif
```

*A.cpp*

```
#include "A.h"

#include <new>

A::A()
{

}

A::A(int n)
 : n(n), elements(std::vector<A::B>(n))
{

}

int A::defaultMultiply(int x, int y) { return (x * y); }
// special multiplication: integer groups have integer addition modulo the group size as their multiplication
int A::multiply(int x, int y)
{
    int a = x % this->n, b = y % this->n;
    if (a < 0) a += this->n;
    if (b < 0) b += this->n;
    return ((a + b) % n);
}

A::B::B()
 : m(0), 
    parentGroupSize(0), 
    mult(0),
    defMult(&A::defaultMultiply) // right?
{

}

A::B::B(int m, int n, multiplication mult)
 : parentGroupSize(n), mult(mult), defMult(0)
{
    // this->m must be in [0, g->size() - 1], if n is larger than 1
    if (n > 1)
    {
        this->m = m % n;
        if (this->m < 0) this->m = n + this->m;
    }
    else
    {
        this->m = m;
    }
}

A::B A::B::operator*(const A::B& b)
{
    if (this->parentGroupSize == b.parentGroupSize)
    {
        if (this->mult)
        {
            return A::B::B((this->*mult)(this->m, b.m), this->parentGroupSize, &A::B::mult); // I tried using this->mult for last argument, but it wouldn't take it
        }
    }
    return A::B(); // or something similar
}

int A::B::val() const { return this->m; }
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

#include "A.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    A(26);  // didn't implement any methods to get B's from A, since I am merely testing compilation. I'm trying for that ever-elusive MCVE with just this...
}
```

Oh, I also get the following error: `error: pointer to member type 'int (A::)(int, int)' incompatible with object type 'A::B'`

Comment: Define "safest". Also, please remove all irrelevant code, that has nothing to do with the question asked. I doubt that the details of all these mathematical operations are in any way relevant to this question.

Comment: When a B or an A goes out of scope, segfaults don't happen because either infinite destruction loop or leaky pointers, for example.

Comment: They provide the reason why it is being done this way.

Comment: Big fan of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), myself. Damn near eliminates all the goofiness of method pointers when used with `std::bind` or a lambda wrapper. Of course you still have the same problems with variables that may have gone out of scope, but such is life.

Comment: Before you can ask if it's "safe" or not, you need to actually make the code compile. Since your code can't even compile, any discussion of whether this is "safe", or not, in some way, is a moot point.

Comment: The school server doesn't have C++11 :'(

Comment: Bummer. But rejoice regardless. You have `vector`. Your school isn't making you use a 25 year old copy of Turbo C++. If you're stuck with method pointers, [here is a page on making them as painless as possible](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

Comment: Sam, I forgot to ask: how to fix the `error: pointer to member type 'int (A::)(int, int)' incompatible with object type 'A::B'` in the operator? I shall update the question

Comment: @user4581301 the overhead associated with std::function is pretty damned high, though.  Both at a compilation level and a runtime level, so you need to be careful where you use it.   Doubly so because of how convenient it is.

Comment: @xaxxon that doesn't surprise me. Some pretty good voodoo going on in there, and if I've learned anything from decades of fantasy RPGs, it's high magic (and rule books) always has a high price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't that you're *passing* a member-function (as an argument) to the constructor of an object of a different type than the member-function class type; the problem is that you're *calling* the member function with the wrong type. The compiler error you're getting is actually quite clear on this: a pointer-to-member *must* be used with the same class-type for which it was declared (or a derived type), because otherwise it would be meaningless.

Note that inner classes are not *derived* classes; a `B` object *is not* a specialized type of `A`. (I think you already realize this, but I want to be clear.) So when you try to invoke a method of `A` with an object-instance of type `B`, you have asked for something that is completely nonsensical.

So, there are two options:

- Use pointer-to-member-of-`B` instead of pointer-to-member-of-`A`. There's never any reason to invoke the members with objects of type `A`, so it's unclear why you thought a pointer-to-member-of-`A` would be useful here.
- Use non-member pointers. Note that your `defaultMultiplication` type already *is* a non-member function. Note that non-members can still take instances of `B` as arguments; they just have a much simpler syntax.

Comment: "a pointer-to-member must be used with the same class-type for which it was declared, because otherwise it would be meaningless"  -- pretty sure derived types are fine.

Comment: @xaxxon Well, obviously, as per my second paragraph, which states that derived types *are* instances of the base-type, at least from the perspective of using pointers-to-members with pointers-to-objects.

Comment: Someone may stop reading when they see that they cannot do something, though -- before they get to the next part that says that the preceding part wasn't correct.  Might as well just make it correct from the start.  Besides, it's an excuse to use the word "covariant".

Comment: This answer was the basis that I have been looking for all this time! I implemented the first option, as that is more in-line with the mathematical definition of group (an object that **has** multiplication). All I had to do was create private constructor that creates an "empty copy" of A, to use for invoking the function pointers. I also wrote `helperFunction` to handle the invocations.

Comment: I wish I had the heart and open-mindedness to consider this implementation via function pointers right from the get-go!

Comment: @MikeWarren As a mathematics major myself, I definitely understand your inclination to make the multiplication operation a member of the group class. But I wouldn't instantiate an empty instance to call it. Instead consider a static member function (pointer).

Comment: @xaxxon I don't think the original was "wrong", per se, and I don't really want to introduce more confusion by adding unnecessary vocabulary, but I have added a parenthetical to clarify that subtypes also qualify.